# Nginx Substitution Module

Tags: nginx

To start, here's what I am trying to do: I have a JavaScript file that contains a variable for the remote address of the client. By default the variable is set to `0.0.0.0`. As Nginx is sending the file I would like to replace the 0's with the $remote_addr variable in Nginx. So basically here's what I've got:

JavaScript Test File:

```
remote_addr = '0.0.0.0';
alert(remote_addr);
```

Config File for Nginx:

```
location /path/to/my.js {
  alias /real/path/to/my.js
  sub_filter "0.0.0.0" $remote_addr;
  sub_filter_once off;
  sub_filter_types application/x-javascript;

  autoindex on;
}
```

When I try the request, I still see 0.0.0.0 in the returned file. I've tried also using simply "Hello World" instead of $remote_addr and still see my default value.

The output of `nginx -V` is as follows:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.2.7                                                                                             
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx --add-module=/home/vagrant/nginx/echo-nginx-module-0.42 --with-http_sub_module --with-pcre=/home/vagrant/nginx/pcre-8.32
```

**Update**

I am still having the issue, but have updated my Nginx config. I did a curl of the JS file and see that Nginx is setting the Content-Type header to `application/x-javascript` so I added `sub_filter_types application/x-javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your ".js" file has "text/html" mime-type?

> *syntax:*     sub_filter_types mime-type ...;
>
> *default:*    sub_filter_types **text/html**;
>
> *context:*    http, server, location
>
> Enables string replacement in responses with the specified MIME types
>   in addition to “text/html”. The special value “*” matches any MIME
>   type (0.8.29).

@ http://nginx.org/r/sub_filter_types

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my question that I added in sub_filter_types of application/javascript and application/x-javascript.

Comment: Turns out I was spelling application wrong in my mime type.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to make a basic replacement of IP addresses with domain names in my .js files, but rewrite have not started to work till the moment I have added following mime type in my nginx config:

```
sub_filter_types application/javascript application/x-javascript;
```

The location config is the following:

```
location ~* ^.+\.js$ {

    sub_filter "ip-address" "domain-name";
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types application/javascript application/x-javascript;

}
```